# Private Beta for 22+ days?

Tags: support

The email we all received on 27 April contained:

> Q: How long will the private beta last? 
> A: Private betas generally
> last 1-2 weeks while you prepare the site for opening day. Once the
> site is populated with questions, and its initial scope established,
> we'll open it up for public beta.

In my experience sites in the past have remained in Private Beta for up to 3 weeks, but (until now) has it ever lasted longer? The last two sites to enter Public Beta were Drones (after 14 days) and Matter Modeling (after 21 days) but we're now almost done our 22nd day in Private Beta here.

Perhaps to help relieve a bit of the anxiety that some people might be experiencing (the email suggested 1-2 weeks and previous experience suggests up to 3 weeks but I think no longer than that), could we get some feedback on how the site is doing and what things need to improve in order to enter Public Beta?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The Community Team](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/208518) is currently evaluating the site for the eligibility to transition out of the Private Beta phase. The phase can last up to 4 weeks, which we'll be completing next Tuesday — the email you referenced could use some updatin', clearly, so good catch!

In any case, you can expect a post announcing what's next for this site next week — be on the lookout for that! ^_^

Comment: What are the eligibility criteria?  I thought that StackExchange is predominantly algorithm driven.