# We may need to promote the site more (still in Private Beta!)

Tags: discussion, support, site-promotion

Sorry everyone, that I have been a bit tied up with some non-StackExchange things in the last couple weeks. I was meaning to participate more and write this post earlier, but time was tight.

As mentioned [here](https://cardano.meta.stackexchange.com/a/47/149), at 22 days we still hadn't satisfied the eligibility criteria, so we were kept in Private Beta for longer than usual (I've only seen them last up to 3 weeks which would be 21 days).

**We *might* be needing 150+ high-quality questions** and right now we have only 180 *total* questions, so if 30 of them are "low-quality" (net score below three?) then we need to get more ***high-quality*** material (like *really good questions* not just "how does plutus work") here in order not to be permanently shut down and to have all our hard-work done for nothing.

I recommend to advertise the site a bit more on the various communities: Plutus, Cardano Reddit, etc.

Unfortunately we have 4 weeks to demonstrate our worth here and 4 weeks are almost up, so if you want this site to survive, now's the time to act! CMs: I meant to write this last week when I was confused why we were still in Private Beta longer than what I thought was the maximum (21) days, but JNat replied 2 days later and by then I was tied up with some things at work (non-SE related). In case the community didn't quite realize how Priavte beta works and that it can only be temporary if we don't work hard, would you consider giving us a few more days to see if the above announcements help drastically improve the quantity of *good* questions?

Comment: @StephaneRolland we entered public beta at 12:31pm EST.  Can you check when my post was written by hovering on the "2 hours ago" if you're on desktop? I'm on phone. A bit busy today. Will definitely reword this. Congratulations! We made it!!

Comment: FYI: https://cardano.meta.stackexchange.com/q/51/26

Comment: How should we deal with questions that are no longer relevant?  e.g. What should we do to this post now that we are out of private beta?  close, flag or leave?

Comment: @gRebel I accepted your answer, and it's clear to anyone that sees this question that we have now entered Public Beta. Typically meta posts like these don't get closed just because they are no longer relevant, for example when an election/call-for-nominations is over, the meta post will still be up forever even though the election is no longer going on. This post is still relevant in that it's still valuable for us to get more **high-quality** questions asked and to promote this site as widely as possible. Having starting the Matter Modeling SE myself, from experience I know we need people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of private beta now.  Thanks for the effort Nike. Time to close as answered?